# copy postgres to csv without psql output in first three rows

Tags: bash, postgresql, copy, pg-dump

I'm trying to dump a postgres table into a csv with

```
psql $DATABASE_CON_INFO -c "Copy foo_table To STDOUT With CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',';" > tmp/foo_table.csv
```

This command works but when I look at tmp/foo_table.csv the top 3 rows 
are

```
Null display is "(null)".
Expanded display is used automatically.
Timing is on.
```

Then there is the header of the table and the content of the table.  I don't want the csv to include this information.  I could write bash code to just delete the first first three rows but that is messy (e.g., what if the number of unwanted rows changes down the road or on a different machine?)

Does anyone know how I write the output to foo_table without including those first three rows?

Answer (score 0):

ahh.. of course, find the solution now that I posted a question.
add

```
--no-psqlrc
```

take a look at:
https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/MODULES-5374

In PostgreSQL 9.6, the behaviour of psql has changed so that -c no longer implies --no-psqlrc. This means that if a system psqlrc is in place, it will be applied by default.